# How can I split a 2 or more digit integer into a linear combination of single digit integers?

Tags: python

If I have the number 10, I'm looking for a way to split it into a linear combination of single-digit integers such as 9 + 1, 8 + 2, 7 + 3, etc. Preferably, it should be the smallest number of single-digit integers that add up to the target but not necessary. This should also work for any number of digits greater than or equal to 2.

Language is not important, just looking for a conceptual solution.

Comment: So why not keep adding 9 until the remainder is one digit, and add that one too?

Comment: ...[https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) - `b=9`.

Comment: maybe run `for`-loop which substracts `1`, `2`, etc. and check if result is smaller then `10`

Answer (score 1):

IIUC (and as hinted in the comments) you can find the number of time 9 is found and add the remainder (with help of [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod)):

```
n = 123
d,r = divmod(n, 9) # (13, 6) i.e. 123 = 13*9+6
out = [9]*d+[r]
# [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 6]

sum(out)
# 123
```